# Quasar framework autocomplete not showing text in list

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using the latest version of quasar (0.17) and I'm trying to use the autocomplete component. I'm able to filter the list and select a value but the text in the autocomplete list is not showing:

[image]

Here is the definition:

```
<q-field :error="$v.clientInfo.name.$error" error-label="Client name is required">
  <q-input placeholder="Start typing a client's name" float-label="Client Name" type="text" v-model="clientInfo.name" @blur="$v.clientInfo.name.$touch" :before="getIcon('perm_identity')" clearable>

      <q-autocomplete :min-characters="0" :value-field="v => `${ v.name }  (${ v.phone })`" :static-data="{field: 'name', list: clients}" :filter="myFilter" />

  </q-input>
</q-field>
```

And the clients array:

```
clients: [{
        name: 'client 1',
        phone: '0545684562'
      }, {
        name: 'client 2',
        phone: '0556843544'
      }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently each object in the list MUST contain value/label, so I changed my data to look like this:

```
clients: [{
    label: 'client 1',
    value: 'client 1',
    phone: '0545684562'
  }, {
    label: 'client 2',
    value: 'client 2',
    phone: '0556843544'
  }]
```

and the template to:

```
<q-field :error="$v.clientInfo.name.$error" error-label="Client name is required">
  <q-input placeholder="Start typing a client's name" float-label="Client Name" type="text" v-model="clientInfo.name" @blur="$v.clientInfo.name.$touch" :before="getIcon('perm_identity')" clearable>

      <q-autocomplete :min-characters="0" :value-field="v => `${ v.value}  (${ v.phone })`" :static-data="{field: 'value', list: clients}" :filter="myFilter" />

  </q-input>
</q-field>
```

And it works!